# finding binaries/files/libraries not in Path -- specifically gcj

Tags: solaris, package-management, gcc

I am trying to build pdftk, which apparently requires gcj. Since it is not already in my path, I can either add the directory holding gcj to my path or define the path in the pre-made Makefile.

The problem is that I have no idea:

a) where gcj is, and
b) whether it exists on the server at all (at least in such a way I can add to path).

This problem has come up more than once in my previous attempts to build binaries from source, so I'm hoping I can ask two questions at once to fix my current issue and avoid this issue in the future...

1. Is there a way to add EVERYTHING I have read/execute permission into my path? Sub-question, is this a bad idea?
2. Does `whereis` only search my path? Is there some equivalent for finding files/directories I need without having to search the ENTIRE host and getting access-denied for every other directory?
3. Is there a way I can know for sure if a library/binary is definitely not available vs. just not in my path?
4. Is there a way to tell, specifically for `gcc` if `gcj` is available?
5. Can I compile gcj to my user directory without having to compile all of gcc with it?
6. Is there a (universal) way, when building a binary, to flag the compile or make file to deal with any dependencies as it finds them rather than simply failing?
7. Does a typical user on a shared-host situation have the ability to use the OS package library to get packages at the user-level?

Answer (score 2):

> (1.) Is there a way to add EVERYTHING I have read/execute permission into my path? Sub-question, is this a bad idea?

...it's a bad idea for security reasons.

> (2.) Does whereis only search my path? Is there some equivalent for finding files/directories I need without having to search the ENTIRE host and getting access-denied for every other directory?

You could use locate (or glocate [available in findutils from OpenCSW](http://www.opencsw.org/packages/CSWfindutils)) with the -r option which allows to use regular expressions: `glocate -r /gcj$`

> (3.) Is there a way I can know for sure if a library/binary is definitely not available vs. just not in my path?

glocate can tell you that, assuming that `gupdatedb` has been recently run.

> (4.) Is there a way to tell, specifically for gcc if gcj is available?

The best way of going about it is to scan the installed packages.  The list of installed files is in `/var/sadm/install/contents`.

> (5.) Can I compile gcj to my user directory without having to compile all of gcc with it?

Haven't tried, but you would still need to go through a lot of hassle.  It's probably best to grab [an already available gcj binary](http://www.opencsw.org/packages/CSWgcc4java). If you have to compile it yourself, then it's best to use existing build descriptions, such as [this one](https://gar.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/gar/csw/mgar/pkg/gcc4/trunk/).

> (6.) Is there a (universal) way, when building a binary, to flag the compile or make file to deal with any dependencies as it finds them rather than simply failing?

I assume you're thinking of something along the lines of Gentoo's emerge, which downloads and installs the dependent packages before it compiles the one you wanted.  It's not easily done; especially if you compile everything as a regular user, because you need then to use a chroot environment. It's a good idea, but not trivial to do.

> (7.) Does a typical user on a shared-host situation have the ability to use the OS package library to get packages at the user-level?

What do you mean by *get packages*? If what you want is to extract the contents of a .pkg file, you can use the pkgtrans command, like this: `pkgtrans foo.pkg ./ all` 
However, there's also a possibility of doing something like [pbuilder](http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/pbuilder-doc/pbuilder-doc.html) which creates a chroot environment, in which you do your compilation as well as package installations, all in the home directory.

Back to the gcj question, I think you need to specify the build time dependencies of your makefile and depend on a package that contains gcj, in a known path, and then you can use that path in your build description.

Generally, if you're in a shared hosting, compiling packages is going to be a pain, it's much better to find a system when you can install and remove packages, and write to /usr.

It's also a good idea to use some kind of a build framework, such as [GAR](http://gar.sf.net), which does all the right things and removes lots of annoyances: it checks the build time dependencies, downloads tarballs, verified checksums, extracts, applies patches if any, configures, builds, installs, and makes a package, and you can specify everything in a single Makefile. Learning to use such a framework requires a bit of time, but if you tend to build packages yourself, the time spend on learning will pay off quickly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it's a bad idea for security reasons. A malicious script or program, or a simple mistake could be a real problem.
2. `whereis` searches the obvious places like `/bin`, `/usr/bin` and others. See the man page FILES section

You can use `locate` if it's available or `find` otherwise:

```
locate gcj
```

or

```
find / -name gcj
```

Answer (score 0):

1: Nobody does that -> bad idea.

2 + 3: The sure way is:

```
pkginfo | grep -i gcj         # (Solaris specific)
find / -name gcj 2>/dev/null
```

4: Don't know.

5: Probably, and it is obviously a lot of manual work.

6: No. In Makefile, you can just append to PATH any directories that usually hold gcj (your educated guess). This will not hurt anyone.

7: No, it is up to admin to install a package. But you don't need to be an admin to extract the files contained in the package to your home directory:

```
pkgtrans my-gcj.pkg .     # (Solaris specific) converts package to a "filesystem format package" (i.e. directory tree)
```

The software will rarely be usable after such substraction (bad ownership, bad path, bad library paths, bad config file paths, no installation script executed, no pre-requisites checked, ...). Such operation is also possible not only on Solaris, but on most other Unix/Linux flavors - using their packaging tools.